# How to express RDF triple metadata?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, triplestore, triples

In addition to storing triples like `"Maine Coon" ex:instanceOf "cat breed"` I'd like to store triples describing other triples. For example, imagine a triple above had IRI `foo`, I'd like to store `<foo> meta:createdAt "11-11-2018"` or `<foo> meta:createdBy <someUserIRI>`.

Is this possible? Is this supported by existing triplestores?
Are there conventional ways for doing this? (Conventional meta ontologies?) Is this a bad idea?

Comment: More concrete answers would be particular ontologies of (RDF) *provenance*, e. g. [PROV-O](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/), or triplestore specific solutions, e. g. Blazegraph's [Reification Done Right](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/Reification_Done_Right)...

Comment: And I'd distinguish "metadata" and "additional information", though modelling approaches might be common... The latter is rather "real world"/"subject field" information, for which three elements of a single triple are not enough...

Comment: @StanislavKralin The Reification Done Right link with statements as subjects and objects is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!